# Setting my production and staging environment for sharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am setting up my staging and production environment for SharePoint 2013. On the staging environment I am planning to install the following:-

-Microsoft Visual studio 2012.

-Microsoft Team foundation server 2012.

-SharePoint server 2013 RTM.

-Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (SP1) Standard

-SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1

So I have the following main two questions:-

1- Are the above software enough to set up my staging environment. Or I need addition software?
2- On the production server I will have to install the same software but without the Microsoft Visual studio 2012 &Microsoft Team foundation server 2012, Or I will need additional software?

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you plan to do development on your staging environment (which will thus make it more a DEV environment than a "real" staging one) you don't need to VS & TFS on it as you can safely deploy WSP / Apps without Visual Studio.

If it's a dev environment, I'd rather put TFS outside the group (unless you have access to a large amount of memory) or use the TFS online environment from Microsoft.

For the Production box you "just" need the server OS, SQL Server instance and of course SharePoint 2013 binaries.

Both environments need to be part of a domain (unless you make the server a DC which is not supported for a production environment).

Answer (score 2):

That is the required software for developing for SharePoint. You will need to make sure you use the 64bit versions.

[This TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303424.aspx) will walk you through the install process. It also lists everything that is required and what order to install them.